# Can't select field of a view

Tags: database, oracle, view, plsql

I got this Oracle view:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW "VALIDA_CADVEN_VIEW" ("SETOR_INI", "NOME_REP_INI", "RE_REP_INI", "TARGET_REP_INI", "SETOR_FIM", "NOME_REP_FIM",
                                                "RE_REP_FIM", "TARGET_REP_FIM", "Situacao", "Causa") AS 
SELECT I.SETOR, I.NOME_REP, I.RE_REP, I.TARGET_REP,
        F.SETOR, F.NOME_REP, F.RE_REP, F.TARGET_REP, 'Não existe no arquivo atual' Situacao, 'Arquivo' Causa
FROM ZCADVEN_INI I 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM ZCADVEN_FIM WHERE RE_REP IS NOT NULL ) f
ON I.RE_REP = F.RE_REP
WHERE F.RE_REP IS NULL
AND I.RE_REP IS NOT NULL

UNION

SELECT I.SETOR, I.NOME_REP, I.RE_REP, I.TARGET_REP,
        F.SETOR, F.NOME_REP, F.RE_REP, F.TARGET_REP, 'Não existe no arquivo anterior' Situacao, 'Arquivo' Causa
FROM ZCADVEN_FIM F 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM ZCADVEN_INI WHERE RE_REP IS NOT NULL ) I
ON I.RE_REP = F.RE_REP
WHERE I.RE_REP IS NULL
AND F.RE_REP IS NOT NULL

UNION

SELECT I.SETOR, I.NOME_REP, I.RE_REP, I.TARGET_REP,
        F.SETOR, F.NOME_REP, F.RE_REP, F.TARGET_REP, 'Há divergências' Situacao, 'Target' Causa
FROM ZCADVEN_FIM F 
INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM ZCADVEN_INI WHERE RE_REP IS NOT NULL ) I
ON I.RE_REP = F.RE_REP
WHERE I.TARGET_REP <> F.TARGET_REP

UNION


SELECT I.SETOR, I.NOME_REP, I.RE_REP, I.TARGET_REP,
        F.SETOR, F.NOME_REP, F.RE_REP, F.TARGET_REP, 'Há divergências' SITUACAO, 'Nome' CAUSA
FROM ZCADVEN_FIM F 
INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM ZCADVEN_INI WHERE RE_REP IS NOT NULL ) I
ON I.RE_REP = F.RE_REP
WHERE I.NOME_REP <> F.NOME_REP

UNION

SELECT I.SETOR, I.NOME_REP, I.RE_REP, I.TARGET_REP,
        F.SETOR, F.NOME_REP, F.RE_REP, F.TARGET_REP, 'Há divergências' Situacao, 'Setor' Causa
FROM ZCADVEN_FIM F 
INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM ZCADVEN_INI WHERE RE_REP IS NOT NULL ) I
ON I.RE_REP = F.RE_REP
WHERE I.SETOR <> F.SETOR

UNION

SELECT I.SETOR, I.NOME_REP, I.RE_REP, I.TARGET_REP,
        F.SETOR, F.NOME_REP, F.RE_REP, F.TARGET_REP, 'OK' Situacao, '-' Causa
FROM ZCADVEN_FIM F 
INNER JOIN ZCADVEN_INI  I
ON I.RE_REP = F.RE_REP
AND I.SETOR = F.SETOR
AND I.NOME_REP = F.NOME_REP
AND I.TARGET_REP = F.TARGET_REP
```

Now, in certain point I need to do this simple `SELECT`:

```
SELECT CAUSA FROM VALIDA_CADVEN_VIEW
```

And I get this error:

```
ORA-00904: "CAUSA": "%s: invalid identifier"
```

Any ideas of what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you created the view with "Causa" in double quotes, case is significant. You will have to do this:

```
SELECT "Causa" FROM valida_cadven_view;
```

I would recommend you re-create your view with upper case identifiers. Either leave the double quotes off or make the identifier upper case:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW VALIDA_CADVEN_VIEW 
    (SETOR_INI, NOME_REP_INI, RE_REP_INI, TARGET_REP_INI, SETOR_FIM
   , NOME_REP_FIM, RE_REP_FIM, TARGET_REP_FIM, Situacao, Causa) AS
```

or

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW "VALIDA_CADVEN_VIEW" 
   ("SETOR_INI", "NOME_REP_INI", "RE_REP_INI", "TARGET_REP_INI", "SETOR_FIM"
  , "NOME_REP_FIM", "RE_REP_FIM", "TARGET_REP_FIM", "SITUACAO", "CAUSA") AS
```

Unless you have a really compelling reason to use lower case in your identifiers, I'd recommend not using them. They are a major source of confusion, as you can see.